How to Implement a 3 way relationship in odoo
I have 3 models. Module 1 has a One2many relationship with module 2. Module 2 has One2many relationship with Module 3. I am trying to use a View Created for Module 1 to enter data into all the Three modules. The code is provided below. of the models and the views. When I try to add data into Module 3. I am getting the following error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Apps\hrms\odoo\models.py", line 5322, in _update_cache
    field_values = [(fields[name], value) for name, value in values.items()]
  File "C:\Apps\hrms\odoo\models.py", line 5322, in <listcomp>
    field_values = [(fields[name], value) for name, value in values.items()]
KeyError: 'name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Apps\hrms\odoo\http.py", line 1632, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
  File "C:\Apps\hrms\odoo\service\model.py", line 133, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "C:\Apps\hrms\odoo\http.py", line 1659, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
  File "C:\Apps\hrms\odoo\http.py", line 1863, in dispatch
    result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "C:\Apps\hrms\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 154, in _dispatch
    result = endpoint(**request.params)
  File "C:\Apps\hrms\odoo\http.py", line 716, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "c:\apps\hrms\addons\web\controllers\dataset.py", line 42, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "c:\apps\hrms\addons\web\controllers\dataset.py", line 33, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Apps\hrms\odoo\api.py", line 468, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Apps\hrms\odoo\api.py", line 453, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Apps\hrms\odoo\models.py", line 6572, in onchange
    record._update_cache(changed_values, validate=False)
  File "C:\Apps\hrms\odoo\models.py", line 5328, in _update_cache
    value = field.convert_to_cache(value, self, validate)
  File "C:\Apps\hrms\odoo\fields.py", line 2980, in convert_to_cache
    id_ = comodel.new(value, origin=origin).id
  File "C:\Apps\hrms\odoo\models.py", line 5754, in new
    record._update_cache(values, validate=False)
  File "C:\Apps\hrms\odoo\models.py", line 5324, in _update_cache
    raise ValueError("Invalid field %r on model %r" % (e.args[0], self._name))
ValueError: Invalid field 'name' on model 'zm.strategic.plans'

The above server error caused the following client error:
null

It is saying that the field is invalid on the model..
Below is the code for the models...
from odoo import api, fields, models


class StrategicPlans(models.Model):
    _name = "zm.strategic.plans"
    _description = "National Strategic Plans"
    _rec_name = "doc_title"

    doc_title = fields.Char(string="Title", required="true")
    level = fields.Selection([
        ('1', 'National'),
        ('2', 'Ministerial')
    ])
    ministry = fields.Char(string="Ministry")
    period = fields.Char(string="Plan Year")
    objective_ids = fields.One2many('zm.strategic.objective', 'objective_id', string='Strategic Objectives',
                                    copy=True, auto_join=True, ondelete='cascade')


class Objective(models.Model):
    _name = 'zm.strategic.objective'
    _description = 'Strategy'

    name = fields.Char(string='Objective', required=True)
    objective_id = fields.Many2one('zm.strategic.plans', string='Objective', required=True,
                                   index=True, copy=False)
    objective = fields.Char(string="Strategic Objectives", required="true")
    strategy_obj_ids = fields.One2many('zm.strategic.strategy', 'strategy_id', string='Strategies',
                                       copy=True, auto_join=True)


class Strategy(models.Model):
    _name = 'zm.strategic.strategy'
    _description = 'Strategy'

    name = fields.Char(string='Strategy', required=True)
    strategy_id = fields.Many2one('zm.strategic.plans', string='Objective', required=True,
                                  index=True, copy=False)


Below is the code for the view that is suppose to handle all of this..
</odoo>
    <record id="view_strategic_plan_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">zm.strategic.plans.form</field>
        <field name="model">zm.strategic.plans</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <field name="doc_title"/>
                        <field name="period"/>
                        <field name="level"/>
                    </group>
                    <notebook>
                        <page string="Strategic Objectives">
                            <field name="objective_ids" context="{'default_strategic_plan_id': active_id}" mode="tree,form">
                                <form>
                                    <group>
                                        <field name="name" />
                                        <field name="objective" invisible="1" />
                                    </group>
                                    <notebook>
                                        <page string="Strategies">
                                            <field name="strategy_obj_ids" context="{'default_strategic_objective_id': active_id}" mode="tree,form">
                                                <form>
                                                    <group>
                                                        <field name="name" />
                                                        <field name="strategy_id" invisible="1" />
                                                    </group>
                                                </form>
                                            </field>
                                        </page>
                                    </notebook>
                                </form>
                            </field>
                        </page>
                    </notebook>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <!--The core code that contains the action-->
    <record id="action_strategic_plan" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Strategic Plans</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">zm.strategic.plans</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form,kanban,pivot</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="o_view_nocontent_smiling_face">
            </p>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>

I tried defining the context in which to access the fields. I am able to see the field and the name but I cannot add information through that field. I used the code below
context="{'default_strategic_objective_id': active_id}" mode="tree,form"


In Odoo 10, you should see the following error message: View type 'form' is not supported in X2Many.

Are you sure? As long as i know, sale.order.order_line field has a form view in sale.order view.

You're right, but in his example, the form view is inside an X2Many field inside a form view which is also inside an X2many field
